# How long should mkfs.fat take to format a 64GB microSDXC Card?

Tags: mkfs

I am attempting to format a possibly-broken microSDXC card. I issued the following command:

```
$ sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -v /dev/sdi1
```

The following output was generated immediately, and the command is still running after half an hour:

```
mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
/dev/sdi1 has 64 heads and 32 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x8000;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 124702720 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 64 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 15219 sectors, and provides 1948003 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is 7e5c8413, no volume label.
```

Should I expect it to take this long?

`ps ax` states the process is in `D+` (uninterruptible sleep):

```
7113 pts/6    D+     0:00 [mkdosfs]
```

Comment: If it helps you any it took longer then that for mine on a i5 with 8GB of RAM.

Comment: Check the kernel logs (`/var/log/kern.log` or some other file in `/var/log` (depending on the distribution) or `dmesg` command). State D+ means that an I/O operation is in progress; probably the card or reader is generating I/O errors and the driver is doing something time-consuming like resetting and retrying.

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I don't know if the time I/O operations takes is reasonable:

1. Monitor with iotop if there is a load on the device.
2. Check log files (journalctl -xb on fedora) for errors.

If by now it still didn't finish, the device probably have a problem.

Comment: In order to answer the question's title: It should take a couple of seconds at most. The data written to the drive for a FAT32 file system amount to a couple of bytes.